# are websockets not supported in Firefox 19?

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

i am trying to write a websocket page, and it works in Chrome and some other browsers on my Ubuntu machine.
however, firefox would not run the websocket part, and both window[WebSocket] and window[MozWebSocket] return "undefined". does firefox not support websockets?

Comment: Open up your console Ctrl+Shift+K and try `typeof WebSocket`, it should return `"function"` on Firefox.

Comment: --
`[22:47:46.285] typeof WebSocket
[22:47:46.287] "undefined"`

Answer (score 0):

Use (from [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/WebSockets_reference/WebSocket)):

```
var mySocket = new WebSocket("ws://www.example.com/socketserver", "protocol");
```

It is supported from Firefox 6.0 (known as `MozWebSocket` prior to Fx 11 - see @Dracs' comment).

Comment: WebSockets were disabled by default in versions 4 and 5 due to security issue in the protocols design. WebSockets were also prefixed as MozWebSocket from version 6 until version 11.

Comment: no go. websocket is not created. this is firefox 19 on Linux64, Mozzila/5.0, Gecko 20100101

Answer (score 0):

Extensions like TorButton can set `network.websocket.enabled` to `false` in `about:config`. Make sure it's `true`.